# I can not export the preseed.cfg file with kickstart configurator

Tags: 16.04, preseed, kickstart

I would like to create a preseed.cfg file for able to construct a Virtual Machine Vagrant automatically (with packer tool).

For this I find a "kickstart configurator" application in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I installed this with this package : apt-get install system-config-kickstart
based on this topic : [Automatic Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/s390x/ch04s03.html)

but I don't have possibility to export or backup my script cfg with this tool like this video : [VIDEO for kickstart tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAGGtYwHI5E)

This is my screenshoot ubuntu : 
[image]
You can that I have nothing kind of link or button to export my script cfg

**How can create a preseed.cfg file for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS compatibility ?
Why my system-config-kickstart disable the export in file cfg ?**

Comment: You should have a menu bar which offers you options

Comment: I know, this is all the reason of this topic :) Why or How find or retrieve this

Comment: I'm without a clue tho, i just installed `system-config-kickstart`on my 16.04 instalation to test and i simply have the menu, maybe try a reinstall `apt-get install --reinstall system-config-kickstart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu is only displayed if you have permission to write to the directory. Run chmod or sudo if applicable and then you should have a menu.

Comment: I resolve my issue with reinstall differently my kickstart application. I don't remember the detail of that but I think that is the logic (which you say). For resume : install application with good right and sure that you have permission for write in directory. Thank you for your reply I validate.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue!